# How to send a notification on Android extracting data from the Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

I know Firebase contains a section to send notifications, writing your message in console, but I want to get the values from a table to display the values in a notification. Is this possible?

Comment: Something like this? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did:

//Firebase Context
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        //URL database firebase
       Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //DataSnapshot para leer datos de un bd
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //Get Actual Value(getchildren)
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting the data from snapshot
                Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                //Intent(Get components GUI)
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                //Allow External Application(PendingIntent)
                PendingIntent pInent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                //Notificacion


                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        //Propiedades
                        .setContentTitle("Notificacion")
                        .setSound(Uri.EMPTY)

                        .setContentText("Nombre: "+person.getName()+"\t\tDireccion: "+person.getAddress())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.bus)
                        .setContentIntent(pInent).getNotification();


                //Cancel notification
                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                //Get Notification
               NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(1, noti);



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I created two classes. One for the URL from Firebase Database and the other for set and get values "Name" and "Address".